# Google map v2 Marker drag and drop with Alert Android

Tags: android, google-maps

I have implemented movable marker in my map by setting dragchangelistner and setdraggable flag as true.
But when the user tries to drag and drop the marker, i want to show an alert with the message that do you want to update the marker position?
if user says OK then i do something on function onMarkerDragEnd() otherwise i want to move back the marker to its original position.
How can we do this?

Answer (score 0):

Create a standard alert dialog that calls .show in the onMarkerDragEnd method. Save a reference to your objects position in onMarkerDragStart. For example:

```
LatLng markerOriginalPosition;

public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker marker) {
    markerOriginalPosition = marker.getPosition();
}

public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {
dialog.show();

}

public void dialogPositiveAction() {
   // do nothing marker is already set
}

public void dialogNegativeAction() {
    // set back to original position
    mMarker.setPosition(markerOriginalPosition);
}
```

Either via callback or action you can set the positive and negative actions the will occur when a user makes their choice. If they like the new position, (positive action), then do nothing since the marker object is already there. If they want to return it back to the original position, set it to the original positions LatLng.